# How to reset the specific values in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a value like this `115040026`.For example first number starts from `1` the value want to increment `115040026,115040027,115040028` so on

If the value starts from `215040029` i don't want the increment value now my result is like this `215040029` but whats is my expected output is `215040001`

If i change the first number series i want to reset the last digits with starting with `01,02..` and so on..

```
+--------+-----------+
| Server | Port      |
+--------+-----------+
| 1      | 115040027 |
| 2      | 115040028 |
| 3      | 115040029 |
| 4      | 215040001 |
+--------+-----------+
```

when im passing the `$this->mynumber('30', "1");` my next number will be `115040030`

Incase im passing this `$this->mynumber('30', "2");` my next number should be
`215040001`

if `215040001` is already exists my output will be `215040002`

What i tried is

```
 $this->mynumber('29', "1");

 private function mynumber($no, $comid)
     {
         $current_year  = substr(date("Y"), -2); //Get Last Two Digits
         $current_month = date("m");
         $company       = $comid;
         $orderno_len   = strlen($no);
         switch($orderno_len)
         {
             case 1:
             $value = "000".$no;
             break;

             case 2:
             $value = "00".$no;
             break;

             case 3:
             $value = "0".$no;
             break;

             default:
             break;
         }


         return $company.$current_year.$current_month.$value;

     }
```

Comment: Can you please specify clearily what you want? What are the input and expected output values of `gen_orderno`?

Comment: I need a output like this `215040001` if the first value starts with `2` i want to reset the last 3 digits

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you tell us the task you want to implement, and not the implementation itself. Cause currently theres no much sense in it.

Comment: i dont know how to explain more > i need to reset the vaues of last 3 digits

Comment: check the updated question @GinoPane may be understand what i need ?

Comment: check my updated one it will explain u what i exactly need

Comment: What do you expect to get, when you call mynumber('30', "2"), and then mynumber('30', "2") again? It schould be '215040001', '215040001' or '215040001', '215040002'?

Comment: '215040001', '215040002' like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74630/discussion-between-gino-pane-and-user2598136).

Answer (score -1):

Try "modulo" - if you want max value to be 30 use 
 `$number = $number%30`

Examples:

0%30 = 0 
1%30 = 1 
29%30 = 29 
30%30 = 0 
31%30 = 1